# Group argument in fit method - sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run a cross validation with grouped data in Sklearn when I found that the `fit` method

```
fit(X, y=None, groups=None, **fit_params)
```

has a groups argument defined as:

> groups : array-like, with shape (n_samples,), optional
> Group labels for the samples used while splitting the dataset into train/test set.

Is this the same thing as spliting my data with other iterators for grouped data (`GroupKFold`, `LeaveOneGroupOut`)?
If not, what is the proper way to run `GridSeachCV` with grouped data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are same.

Please refer to the documentation of [GridsearchCV `fit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.fit):

> groups : array-like, with shape (n_samples,), optional
>
> ```
> Group labels for the samples used while splitting the dataset into train/test set.
> ```

Comment: I am not sure since the `GroupKFold` object does not receive the groups when instantiated. Instead, groups are passed to the split method and therefore when using it with a `GridSearchCV` the groups must be passed to the fit method.